# local variable and asterisk

Tags: bash, function, shell, variables

I´ve declared a LOCAL variable (a) inside a function that receives the value of first parameter (${1}). When I call it with a with an asterisk in first parameter´s content, the value assignment had a different treatment. Why?

```
# function_name () { local a="${1}"; echo $a; }
# set -xv && function_name "param_1_*" && set +xv
set -xv && function_name "param_1_*" && set +xv
+ set -xv
+ function_name 'param_1_*'
+ local 'a=param_1_*'
+ echo 'param_1_*'
param_1_*
+ set +xv
```

NOTE: **+ local 'a=param_1_*'**  <-- See? the quote is inserted before the variable name "a"

```
# function_name () { a="${1}"; echo $a; }
# set -xv && function_name "param_1_*" && set +xv
+ function_name 'param_1_*'
+ a='param_1_*'
+ echo 'param_1_*'
param_1_*
+ set +xv
```

NOTE: **+ a='param_1_*'** <-- On this case, the quote is inserted after the equal signal

Comment: @Rob: you should probably put that in as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the asterisk is the difference. In your two functions, one is declaring a local and one is setting a shell variable. In the first case you're passing `a=param_1_*` as an argument to the local builtin (and the shell doesn't care that one of those characters is an `*` or an `=`), but in the second the shell is parsing the `a=foo` into its components. In the first case, it makes sense to put quotation marks around the entire argument, which is `a=param_1_*`, but it doesn't make sense in the second, since you couldn't really type `'a=param_1_*'` at a shell prompt and expect the shell to set the a variable.

Answer (score 1):

They're being displayed differently by bash's -x mode, but that doesn't mean bash is treating them differently.  What's happening here is that when bash executes `local a="${1}"`, it parses it into some internal representation (something more complicated than a string), substitutes the first parameter into that, and then notices that -x mode is active.  So what it does is take that internal representation, and un-parses it into a command you could type in to get the same effect.  In general, there will be a number of ways to type in a command that'd produce the same effect (i.e. the internal representation), and it chooses one of these.  It *could* print any of the following:

```
+ local a='param_1_*'
+ local 'a=param_1_*'
+ local $'a=param_1_*'
+ local a=param_1_"*"
+ local a=param_1_\*
```

... or any of a number of other possibilities.  Its choice may not be the one you'd expect, but it's a perfectly valid way of typing in the "same" command.

BTW, as @Rob said, there is a difference in that `a='param_1_*'` and `'a=param_1_*'` are *not* equivalent commands, while `local a='param_1_*'` and `local 'a=param_1_*'` are equivalent.  This is because with the local command, the assignment is essentially a parameter, and quoting around it doesn't matter as much as with a standalone assignment.  Thus, when displaying `a="${1}"`, it could print any of:

```
+ a='param_1_*'
+ a="param_1_*"
+ a=param_1_$'*'
+ a=param_1_\*
```

but not any of these:

```
+ 'a=param_1_*'
+ "a=param_1_*"
+ $'a=param_1_*'
```